# Temporary relocation to Massachusetts

Tags: united-states, taxes, relocation

My company is looking to temporarily (6months) re-locate me to Boston from California. I think I will be keeping my permanent residence as my home address in CA.

My question is, will I need to file taxes in both CA and MA for 2015?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, will I need to file taxes in both CA and MA for 2015?

Yes. You might even end up being resident in both, check MA residency requirements.

Comment: That is what I am struggling with. US Tax confuses the hell out of me! :) Is there a simple rule like, "if you are in MA for x days you file, otherwise you don't"?

Comment: You file regardless since you have MA-sourced income. The question of residency comes when you need to pay MA taxes on out-of-MA income.

Comment: Many companies will provide advice/assistance to folks on temporary assignment, or relocating within the company, out of state. Ask your HR department.

Comment: Don't know about Massachusetts specifically, but if it's like California you would file the non-resident tax return.  And it looks as though it will be simple to keep non-resident status: http://www.mass.gov/dor/individuals/filing-and-payment-information/guide-to-personal-income-tax/residency-status.html#Residency